# "No protocol binding matches the given address" Error

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wcf

I intermittently get the error below when running a WCF service in the VS 2008 developer environment:

> No protocol binding matches the given
>   address
>   'http://0.0.0.0:3371/Common.svc'.
>   Protocol bindings are configured at
>   the Site level in IIS or WAS
>   configuration

The only solution I have found is to reboot the pc and all works again as expected.
How do I prevent this error?
How to I work around it aside from rebooting or changing the port number?

Comment: Could someone explain why this question received a vote to be closed?

Comment: It was voted for close as "belongs on serverfault" - whoever voted for that evidently thought the problem was with your server settings (ie, "Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration") and thinks that moving it may give you a better answer.

Comment: Note that I don't know enough about the question to determine that, so I'm not saying I agree or disagree with that vote to close, but you might want to make it clear in your question that you are seeking a solution from the programming side, and that the server configuration is correct.

Comment: OK. I didn't know clicking on the close button would show me why it was flagged to be closed.  (I thought clicking on 'close' would close the question).  Having looked at Server Fault, I believe this question is more programming related than server configuration related because it is related to the debugging environment of Visual Studio.